# Ribbon on homepage for Product attribute

Tags: product-attribute

I have two kind of Products; Physical and Electronic, on basis of a custom attribute "Product Type".
I want to show a ribbon on my home page for the products with "Product Type = E-Products". 
How can I achieve this thing?

There are many extensions that provide ribbons on basis of Newly Added, Sale, Best Seller and Most Viewed. But I can't find any for product custom attribute.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just do one thing conditionally

you got product id

```
$_product=Mage::Model('catalog/product')->load($id);
if($_product->getData('attribute_code')=='E-Products')
{
   // your e-product image;
}
else
{
 // your another image; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Keyul. Please explain where should I add this code?

Comment: the file which you created for displaying product at home page. find that phtml file and where you need images then you can put the above condition